# Jquery Multiple selector with same attr(href) by different parent element

Tags: jquery

I have the sidebar-left like this:
Div with id: Label content many of label ( a href1, a href2, a href3,...).

Orther I have One post with the footer show the label for this post (Id:footer) and content some (a) tag same the sidebar. Example i choose two (a href1 and a href3 for this post).

Now i want to Select All of the sidebar-left (a element) that href match to my post footer.

Exact that i want to select the element (a) with href1 and href3 in sidebar-left.
If the footer content what ahref so i will select same in sidebar-left to mark it like selected.

mycode: in my site: http://www.kingker.tk/2013/07/tuy-chinh-jw-player.html

```
var labelatfooterofpost = $('div.post-footer .post-labels a').attr('href');
$('#Label a[href='+ labelatfooterofpost +']').parent('li').addClass('label-li-selected').append('<i>test</i>') ;
```

not working. someone help me to solve it. thanks!

Comment: there is no div with #Label

Comment: you mean no div before #Label. i don't think so. i mean just the way to solve the problem. not the syntax. without div before it's also run  well.

Comment: i meant i didnt found any div which have id="Label"

Comment: in my web #sidebar-left-1 > .widget.Label . in the code above i just short the code by use an example (#Label). thank for comment